# How to make a call when click on button in Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sos

I'm working on a project in which I have created a button.I want to add a feature that if I clicked on that button then it will automatically make a call to police number (100).
I have written the code for the same, and when I clicked on that button my mobile phone's dial pad is opening and 100 number is displaying in dial pad.
Is there any way to make a call automatically instead of directing me to dial pad?

Can anyone guide me regarding this please?

Comment: Does this help? https://itnext.io/android-dial-phone-programmatically-5ea3714d801d

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of how you use the intent, this should dial the number directly:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "100"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Here is documentation on both `ACTION_CALL` and `ACTION_DIAL`.

`ACTION_DIAL` will only fill in the number in the dialer:
[Intent.ACTION_DIAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_DIAL)

`ACTION_CALL` will fill in the number in the dialer and attempt to dial it:
[Intent.ACTION_CALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CALL)